# I am working on Ruby on rails but it is giving undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Don't know why my app is throwing error on the registration file.Plz let me know the error.Thank you very much

**Error**
Showing /home/punisher/Desktop/billboard/app/views/register/signup.html.erb where line #36 raised:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #36):

```
<h1 class="Login-here">Register Here</h1>
<%= form_with model: @owner,url:register_path, local: true  do |form| %>
<% if @owner.errors.any? %>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<% @owner.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
<div> <%= message %> </div>
```

**Register_controller**

```
class RegisterController < ApplicationController

def new
    @owner=Owner.new
end

def create
# render plain: "Thanks for registering!"
# render plain: params[:user]
    @owner=Owner.new(owner_params)
    if @owner.save
        session[:owner_id] = @owner.id
        redirect_to login_path
    else
        flash[:error] ="User Not Registered"
        render :signup
        
    end        
end    

private  
def owner_params()
    params.permit(:email, :company_name, :address, :contact_no, :password, :password_confirmation)
end    
end
```

**signup.erb.html**

```
  <body style = "background-color:rgb(92, 179, 196)">


  <div class="tnavbar">
  <div class="tlogo">
      <%= image_tag('1.png', :class => "logoimg") %>
      <h3 class="title"> Out of Home</h3>
  </div>

  <div>
  
  <%= link_to "login", login_path, class:"home-btn"%>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <div class="row loginpagerow">
  <div class="col-1">
  </div>
    <div class="logincol col-5 imagebox">

    <h1 class="headinglogin">Bringing you the best of the best.</h1>
    <%= image_tag('loginpageimage.png', :class => "img") %>

    </div>


    <div class="col-5 logincol loginbox">
        <h1 class="Login-here">Register Here</h1>
        <%= form_with model: @owner,url:register_path, local: true  do |form| %>
          <% if @owner.errors.any? %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <% @owner.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
               <div> <%= message %> </div>
            <% end %>
            </div>
         <% end %>
          <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px">
          <div style="width:45%; height:35vh; margin-left:25px;">
              <%= form.email_field :email ,class: "form-control login-email-field signup-fields", placeholder:"Email" %>
              <%= form.text_field :company_name ,class: "form-control login-email-field signup-fields", placeholder:"Company Name" %>
              <%= form.text_field :address ,class: "form-control login-email-field signup-fields", placeholder:"Address" %>

          </div>
          <div style="width:45%; height:35vh; margin-left:25px;">
             <%= form.telephone_field :contact_no ,class: "form-control login-email-field signup-fields", placeholder:"Contact No" %>
              <%= form.password_field :password ,class: "form-control login-email-field signup-fields", placeholder:"password" %>
              <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation,class: "form-control login-email-field signup-fields", placeholder:"Confirm password" %>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3 login-input">
             <%= form.submit "Signup" ,class: "sign-btn btn btn-primary"%>
          </div>
            
          </div>
          
         
        <% end %>

    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `app/views/register/signup.html.erb` view and Rails expects `signup` method in your `registrations_controller` and is looking for `@owner`
instance method but you don't have `signup` method that's why it's raising an error because `@owner` is `nil`.

```
def signup
  @owner = Owner.new(owner_params)
  ...
end
```